How to render the ModalBottomSheet with TextField immediately above the soft keyboard?
I am working on a small Kotlin Multiplatform project with Compose Multiplatform and I want to use a ModalBottomSheet (using Scrim to block the main content) with a TextField inside.
        if (showBottomSheet) {
            BottomSheet(
                onClick = onClick,
                onDismissRequest = {
                    showBottomSheet = false
                }
            )
        }

The problem is that when the bottom sheet is opened on Android, it goes like this:

BottomSheet is rendered at the bottom of the screen.
Then the text field gains focus and soft keyboard opens and covers the bottom sheet.
Then the bottom sheet is moved above the soft keyboard making it visible again.

All these steps are visible and very annoying even though it happens in only about 1 second.
Could someone maybe recommend a solution for this?
I have tried researching WindowInsets to render the bottom sheet immediately at the correct height including the soft keyboard - but as far as I know it is not possible to know the keyboard height before it is rendered.
I also tried having the bottom sheet to be always rendered but not visible, so I could request focus to its text field to show keyboard, then show the bottom sheet - but I want to have the main content blocked with Scrim option of the ModalBottomSheet as well, so it is not possible like this.

Have you tried using a softInputMode of resize instead of pan?  THe behavior of rendering then moving sounds very much like a pan, whereas a resize should avoid that.
